# What is NSURLErrorCancelled = -999 in iOS?

Tags: ios

Can some one describe how "NSURLErrorCancelled = -999" is used.

Answer (score 8):

From Apple docs:

> NSURLErrorCancelled (-999)
>
> "Returned when an asynchronous load is canceled. A Web Kit framework 
>   delegate will receive this error when it performs a cancel
>   operation on a loading resource. Note that an NSURLConnection or
>   NSURLDownload delegate will not receive this error if the download is
>   canceled."

best thing you can do about it is to ignore this error

```
if ([error code] != NSURLErrorCancelled) {
   //here you'll get a real error 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This error might me caused by an invalid SSL certificate. If the framework you are using to execute the request tests for valid SSL, you should add the host you are trying to connect to on a whitelist of trusted hosts.

Hope that helps anyone :)

Answer (score 2):

When the URL redirects to another URL, we will receive an [NSURLErrorCancelled](http://codehappily.wordpress.com/2013/10/07/ios-uiwebview-errors-to-look-out-for/) error. And  you have assigned a code value of `-999` to that.