# How do I accept a self-signed SSL certificate using iOS 7's NSURLSession

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, https, self-signed

I have the following code (swift implementation):

```
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace protectionSpace: NSURLProtectionSpace) -> Bool
{
    return protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust
}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge)
{
    if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust
    {

        if challenge.protectionSpace.host == "myDomain"
        {
            let credentials = NSURLCredential(forTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust)
            challenge.sender.useCredential(credentials, forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)
        }
    }

    challenge.sender.continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge(challenge)

}
```

It works perfectly in iOS 8.x, **but does not work iOS 7.x**
In iOS 7.x I have error:

*NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)*

Any idea?
thank you!!!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Both `connection:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:` and `connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:` are deprecated in iOS 8 anyway so you should use other methods.

What I am using in my projects is a delegate method of NSURLSessionDelegate. Adhere to that protocol then add this method:

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential!) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, NSURLCredential(forTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust))
}
```

Then, when you use initialize NSURLSession with delegate set to self. For example:

```
var session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue:NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
```

Then use that session instance to call dataTaskWithRequest method on:

```
var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){
    (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        callback("", error.localizedDescription)
    } else {
        var result = NSString(data: data, encoding:
            NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Complete working example can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/edwardmp/a0ffb3ace02ce4392b26).

For security reasons, if you use a self-signed certificate I recommend also implementing public key pinning (https://gist.github.com/edwardmp/df8517aa9f1752e73353)

Comment: Is this at all secure without public key pinning? As far as i can see, you don't check the certificate matches what it should

Comment: How can you check the certificate matches when you don't use public key pinning? Key pinning is not requested, but I recommend it thats why I included the link at the bottom to a snippet..

Comment: The traffic is still encrypted without using public key pinning, but I guess a Man In The Middle attack (MITM) makes it possible to offer another certificate in order to intercept the traffic.

Comment: Does not work for me - I get some "Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999". But it works on with valid certificates.

Comment: @coyer -999 error means that the request is cancelled. Maybe you or some other library you use cancels the request (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25390073/what-is-nsurlerrorcancelled-999-in-ios)? Or maybe something is wrong with the server itself (e.g. the certificate is self signed but the hostname is also incorrect)

Comment: Could you please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56627757/1364053

Answer (score 0):

inherit class with URLSessionDelegate

create a session object

```
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default


let session = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)


 let task = session.dataTask(with: httpRequest as URLRequest, completionHandler: {requestData, response, errorData -> Void in

            if errorData == nil {

                dataCallback(requestData! as NSData)
            }
            else {

                let error = NSError(domain: "Err-1001", code: 11, userInfo:nil)
                failureCallback(error)
            }
        });

        task.resume()
```

Add delegate methad

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didReceive     challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
     completionHandler(
        .useCredential,
        URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
 }
```

add this in your info.plist file

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>xyc.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 5 Solution**

Note These settings are for testing purpose only, don't push changes in production app

**Steps**

1. Add "Allow Arbitrary Loads" key to "YES" under "App Transport Security Settings" in info.plist
2. Create new session object with delegate to self

   let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
   let session = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
3. Implement URLSessionDelegate protocol to current class

   extension YouClass: URLSessionDelegate{
   func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
   completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
   }
   }

Modified version of:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30820452/3754976