# WebView load requset failure

Tags: ios, webview

When my webView first load requset,it is error.

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://v.qq.com/iframe/player.html?vid=k034117nqr8&tiny=0&auto=0,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://v.qq.com/iframe/player.html?vid=k034117nqr8&tiny=0&auto=0

But when i scroll my tabview,my webView will be refresh,then it will be load request success.Why?who knows it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is NSURLErrorCancelled = -999 in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25390073/what-is-nsurlerrorcancelled-999-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem with add a argument in url.Then it will be request different url every time.

```
UIWebView *webView = [self createWebView];
webView.delegate = self;

NSURLComponents *urlCom = [[NSURLComponents alloc] initWithString:self.content];
NSString *timeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
NSURLQueryItem *item = [[NSURLQueryItem alloc] initWithName:@"aaa" value:timeString];
NSMutableArray *array = [urlCom.queryItems mutableCopy];
[array addObject:item];
urlCom.queryItems = array;
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[urlCom URL]]];
```